# Является ли данный код рекурсивным?

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Есть задание

Найти методом деления отрезка пополам минимум функции `f(x) = 7sin(2x)` на отрезке [2, 6] с заданной точностью ε (например, 0.01).
Разумеется, его нужно написать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


const double eps = 0.01;
double a, b, t, x, y, t1, s;

double func(double a, double b)
{
    s = (a + b) / 2;
    y = (7 * sin(2)*s);
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    a = 2;
    b = 6;
    while (abs(b - a) < eps);
    {
        t = (a + b) / 2.0;
        y = 7 * sin(2)*(t - eps);
        x = 7 * sin(2)*(t + eps);
        if (y <= x)
        {
            a = t;
            t1 = func(a, b);
        }
        else
        {
            b = t;
            t1 = func(a, b);
        }
    }
    cout << "Otvet: " << t1;
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что преподаватель говорит, что задача решена не рекурсивно. Я утверждаю что решение рекурсивно, так как функция `double func` принимает значение из функции `int main`. Прав ли я?

Comment: нет, Вы не правы, а "препрод" - прав

Comment: Рекурсия самого алгоритма и рекурсия реализации этого алгоритма на ЯП - разные вещи. Использованный вами алгоритм может и можно назвать условно "рекурсивным" с некоей абстрактной точки зрения, но никакой рекурсии в его реализации у вас нет. Рекурсия реализации в процедурном ЯП - это, традиционно, вызов процедуры/функции из самой себя. Где это у вас?

Comment: @Metod  Возможно, вы правы, и он, "препрод", рекурсивен. Проблема в том, что кроме вас здесь никто не видел этого "препрода", а потому невозможно сказать, рекурсивен ли он или нет.

Comment: @ AnT Что я должен с ним сделать что б он стал рекусивным ?

Comment: @Metod  Вообще-то, обычно в таких спорах все решает сила. Кто из вас сильнее, тот и рекурсивный!

Comment: @Metod: У вас в реализации есть цикл. Цикл легко превратить в рекурсию. Вынесите тело цикла в отдельную функцию, уберите цикл нафиг совсем и замените его хвостовой рекурсией.

Comment: @ AnT а как нибуть без хвостовой рекурсии ?

Comment: @Metod: А почему и откуда вдруг возникло требование "без хвостовой рекурсии"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Верно будет так (примерны код):

```
rec(double a, double b){
      (здесь все ваши действия с синусами)
      if (abs(b - a) < eps)  // проверяем новые значения - надо еще раз пересчитать?
            rec(a, b) // вызываем саму себя с новыми значениями
      else return ... // иначе - возвращаем ответ
  }
```

И в мейне вызываем эту функцию,не забыв передать в нее начальные a и b

Comment: И зачем у вас при найденном решении (`b` отличается от `a` меньше, чем на `eps`) выполняется рекурсивный вызов? и **как** вы получите из него нужную информацию?

Comment: не вдавалась в подробности алгоритма, при каком условии надо еще раз пересчитать - это примерный код, комментари поясняют назначение строк, думаю автор разобрался. Я поясняю значение рекурсии в коде на примере, а не решаю за автора его домашнее задание.

Comment: Видите ли, если человек не понимает простейших вещей - что такое рекурсия - то ваш пример, по-моему, его еще более запутает. Я понимаю, что вы в спешке описались со знаком больше-меньше, но вызов `rec` без возврата информации - это уже не опечатка...

Comment: уговорили ) передадим указатель

Comment: Зачем там указатель? И теперь разность указателей должна стать меньше EPS? И вообще, всё же неверно...

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия достигается в вашем случае с изменением "входимости кода" на уровень выше. Оберните цикл while (точнее, замените цикл на рекурсивный вызов) в функцию, и будет вам то, что хочет препод.

Вот готовое решение:

```
    // Найти методом деления отрезка пополам минимум функции f(x) = 7sin(2x) на отрезке [2, 6] с заданной точностью ε (например, 0.01).

    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

    const double eps = 0.01;
    double a, b, t, x, y, t1, s;

    double func(double a, double b, double e)
    {
        s = (a + b) / 2 ;
        t1 = 7 * sin(2*s + e) ;
        return t1;
    }

    void JustDoIt(double &a,double &b)
    {
                t = (a + b) / 2.0;
                y = func(a, b,   - eps);
                x = func(a, b,  eps);
                if (y >= x)    a = t;
                else   b = t;
                // чек-блок 
                     cout << "t= " << t <<"\n";
                     cout << "a= " << a <<" b=" << b <<"\n";
                     cout << "x= " << x <<" y=" << y <<"\n";
                     cout << "fabs(b - a)= " <<  fabs(b - a) <<"\n";
                // 
               if ( fabs(b - a) < eps) return;
                JustDoIt( a, b);
    }

    int main()
    {
       a = 2;
       b = 6;
       JustDoIt( a, b);
       cout << "Otvet: " << func(a, b,0)<<"\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Вывод:

```
a= 4 b=6
x= 6.91498 y=6.93535
fabs(b - a)= 2
a= 5 b=6
x= -3.86669 y=-3.74922
fabs(b - a)= 1
a= 5 b=5.5
x= -6.99927 y=-6.99989
fabs(b - a)= 0.5
a= 5.25 b=5.5
x= -6.19085 y=-6.12428
fabs(b - a)= 0.25
a= 5.375 b=5.5
x= -6.80666 y=-6.77263
fabs(b - a)= 0.125
a= 5.4375 b=5.5
x= -6.95725 y=-6.94041
fabs(b - a)= 0.0625
a= 5.46875 b=5.5
x= -6.99191 y=-6.98379
fabs(b - a)= 0.03125
a= 5.48438 b=5.5
x= -6.99901 y=-6.99525
fabs(b - a)= 0.015625
a= 5.49219 b=5.5
x= -6.99999 y=-6.99843
fabs(b - a)= 0.0078125
Otvet: -6.99996
```

попутно выявились ошибки в вашем коде: while не выполняется из-за ";" , а блок затем проходит только один раз и вместо abs() нужно использовать fabs().

Comment: Неверно. У тебя [получается](http://ideone.com/Bj9v18) значение функции `-3.80204`, а [должно быть](http://ideone.com/UKkQFI) `-7` в точке `2.35547`.

Comment: да это так, но я не писал алгоритм вычисления, там куча ошибок. просто переделал его в рекурсивный.

Comment: теперь работает ( выдает второй минимум в точке 5.5)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это решение не является рекурсивным. Рекурсия предполагает вызов функции из себя (прямо или косвенно), а в приведённом решении ничего подобного нет.

Более того, приведённое решение визуально кажется мне неверным. Функция не является монотонной, поэтому всякие шаманства со знаками применять, скорее всего, не следует.

На мой взгляд, правильным будет проверять весь отрезок полностью (в условии сказано "методом деления отрезка пополам", но не сказано, что это должен быть бинпоиск, отсекающий половину отрезка).

http://ideone.com/fyRCVW

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double EPS = .01;

double f(double x)
{
    return 7 * sin(2*x);
}

double solve(double l, double r)
{
    double m = l / 2 + r / 2;

    if (r-l < EPS)
        return m;

    double x1 = solve(l, m), x2 = solve(m, r);
    return f(x1) < f(x2) ? x1 : x2;
}

int main()
{
    cout << solve(2, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Ответ: `2.35547`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


const double eps = 0.01;
double a, b, t, x, y, t1, s;

double func(double a, double b)
{
 s = (a + b) / 2;
 t1 = (7 * sin(2)*s);
 return t1;
}
double rec(){
 while (abs(b - a) < eps);
 {
    t = (a + b) / 2.0;
    y = 7 * sin(2)*(t - eps);
    x = 7 * sin(2)*(t + eps);
    if (y <= x)
    {
        a = t;
        t1 = func(a, b);
    }
    else
    {
        b = t;
        t1 = func(a, b);
    }
 }
}

 int main()
 {

 a = 2;
 b = 6;
 rec();
 cout << "Otvet: " << t1;

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @Mike Volzhsky Верно ?

Comment: Нет. В графе выполнения всё еще нет циклов, обычное дерево)